# Collapsible not Working [JSFiddle demo Included]

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to get this collapsible to function normally and show the first set of information when the page is loaded, make it disappear when the user presses "read more", and show new information.

```
<script>
    var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
      coll[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var content = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (content.style.display === "block") {
          content.style.display = "none";
        } else {
          content.style.display = "block";
        }
      });
    }

    function display() {
      var x = document.getElementById("cover");
      if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
      } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
      }
    }

  </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are attaching the onclick=display() to all of your list elements. GetElementById is going to return the first element with the given id, in this case it's always targeting your first cover (if you're triggering that elsewhere in your script). So since every 'read more' list element has the onclick function calling display(), it is always hitting your first element (because it's the first element with the respective id).  What you could do instead pass in the event then use ['closest'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) and pass in the id there (if your intention is to hide the image as well).  If not you can remove the display() on the onclick there.

The other elements are working as expected but you don't see it because your css on the enclosing container is hiding it (if you check your inspector you will notice the css being set as expected).  You might want to add an overflow scroll to scroll within the container limits to see your expanded data, or use something like css flex with minimum height in order to expand the container to see your read more data

Comment: in your css for '.products', where you have height set to 350, change that to min-height: 350, after that when you click read more, your container will expand to fit the new content